# Generating Julia set

Tags: python, numpy, fractals

So, I just wanted to post something on [Rosetta Code](http://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code), and I found this task of generating and plotting a [Julia set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_set): http://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Julia_set. There was already one solution but it was quite inefficient and not Pythonic. Here is my attempt on this:

```
"""
This solution is an improved version of an efficient Julia set solver
from:
'Bauckhage C. NumPy/SciPy Recipes for Image Processing:
 Creating Fractal Images. researchgate. net, Feb. 2015.'
"""
import itertools
from functools import partial
from numbers import Complex
from typing import Callable

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def douady_hubbard_polynomial(z: Complex,
                              *,
                              c: Complex):
    """
    Monic and centered quadratic complex polynomial
    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_quadratic_polynomial#Map
    """
    return z ** 2 + c


def julia_set(*,
              mapping: Callable[[Complex], Complex],
              min_coordinate: Complex,
              max_coordinate: Complex,
              width: int,
              height: int,
              iterations_count: int = 256,
              threshold: float = 2.) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    As described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_set
    :param mapping: function defining Julia set
    :param min_coordinate: bottom-left complex plane coordinate
    :param max_coordinate: upper-right complex plane coordinate
    :param height: pixels in vertical axis
    :param width: pixels in horizontal axis
    :param iterations_count: number of iterations
    :param threshold: if the magnitude of z becomes greater
    than the threshold we assume that it will diverge to infinity
    :return: 2D pixels array of intensities
    """
    imaginary_axis, real_axis = np.ogrid[
                        min_coordinate.imag: max_coordinate.imag: height * 1j,
                        min_coordinate.real: max_coordinate.real: width * 1j]
    complex_plane = real_axis + 1j * imaginary_axis

    result = np.ones(complex_plane.shape)

    for _ in itertools.repeat(None, iterations_count):
        mask = np.abs(complex_plane) <= threshold
        if not mask.any():
            break
        complex_plane[mask] = mapping(complex_plane[mask])
        result[~mask] += 1

    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mapping = partial(douady_hubbard_polynomial,
                      c=-0.7 + 0.27015j)  # type: Callable[[Complex], Complex]

    image = julia_set(mapping=mapping,
                      min_coordinate=-1.5 - 1j,
                      max_coordinate=1.5 + 1j,
                      width=800,
                      height=600)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(image,
               cmap='nipy_spectral',
               origin='lower')
    plt.show()
```

I think it looks good, and it is definitely more efficient. There was just one thing that I was not sure about. I was thinking to take out creating a `complex_plane` to a separate function and pass it as a parameter to `julia_set`. But in this case the `julia_set` wouldn't be a pure function as it would mutate the `complex_plane`. And I prefer my functions not to have any side effects. So I decided to leave it as is.

Any comments on this matter or anything else are welcome.

Here are some examples of output:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### 1. Review

1. Some of the variable names could be improved:

   `complex_plane` is an array of \$z\$ values for each pixel in the image, so naming it `z` would help the reader relate it to the `z` in `douady_hubbard_polynomial`.

   `imaginary_axis` and `real_axis` are only used once in the very next line, so there is no need for them to have long and memorable names. I would use something short like `im` and `re`.

   `result` is an array of iteration counts, so it could be named something like `iterations`.

   `mask` is a Boolean array selecting pixels that have not yet diverged to infinity, so something like `not_diverged` or `live` would convey this better.
2. On each iteration, the iteration counts of the escaped pixels are incremented. This means that some pixels get incremented many times, for example a pixel that escapes on the first iteration gets its count incremented 256 times. It would be more efficient to set the iteration count for each pixel just once. A convenient time to do this is when it escapes.
3. As the number of iterations goes up, the number of pixels that have not escaped to infinity gets smaller and smaller. But the masking operations are always on the whole array. It would be more efficient to keep track of the *indexes* of the pixels that have not escaped, so that subsequent operations are on smaller and smaller arrays.

#### 2. Revised code

```
im, re = np.ogrid[min_coordinate.imag: max_coordinate.imag: height * 1j,
                  min_coordinate.real: max_coordinate.real: width * 1j]
z = (re + 1j * im).flatten()
live, = np.indices(z.shape) # indexes of pixels that have not escaped
iterations = np.empty_like(z, dtype=int)
for i in range(iterations_count):
    z_live = z[live] = mapping(z[live])
    escaped = abs(z_live) > threshold
    iterations[live[escaped]] = i
    live = live[~escaped]
iterations[live] = iterations_count - 1
return (iterations_count - iterations).reshape((height, width))
```

Notes

1. This is about three times as fast as the code in the post.
2. Because we are maintaining an array of indexes, it is convenient to flatten the `z` array and then reshape `iterations` to two dimensions before returning it. If we left the array two-dimensional, there would need to be two arrays of indexes, `live_i` and `live_j`.
3. Pixels that don't escape are given the value `iterations_count - 1` in order to match the code in the post. It would make more sense to use `iterations_count` or a larger value here.
4. The subtraction `iterations_count - iterations` is only there so that the returned values match the code in the post. The subtraction could be omitted if you [reverse the colour map](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap.reversed).

Answer (score 3):

For `douady_hubbard_polynomial`, you're missing a return type.

This:

```
for _ in itertools.repeat(None, iterations_count):
```

can just be

```
for _ in range(iterations_count):
```

I don't see any other obvious issues.

Comment: `itertools.repeat(None, iterations_count)` is much faster for big `int`s since it doesn't require creating redundant objects, you can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9098860/5997596)

Comment: That's pretty cool; I didn't know that. I'd still suggest that it's premature optimization and highly unlikely to be a bottleneck of any significance.

Comment: I did some timings, and it looks like `itertools.repeat` won't be of any help due to breaking out of a loop when the `mask` becomes empty, so it won't reach big `int`s where the difference will be significant. I'm gonna change it to `range`.

Comment: About using the asterisk. I think it is a good practice to [force a user to use keyword arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965271/forced-naming-of-parameters-in-python). When you said about *arbitrary arguments*, I think, you referred to [another thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125218/arbitrary-number-of-arguments-in-a-python-function) which is not my case.

Comment: @Georgy I removed my asterisk feedback from the answer. That said, this is a style decision, and one I disagree with. It should be left to the caller to determine whether adding explicit kwarg names makes the call more clear, or whether the parameters being passed are obvious and the code can be made more terse.

Answer (score 1):

This is a minor change, with a 50% improvement to @gareth's answer. Changing

`escaped = abs(z_live) > threshold` to

`escaped = z_live.real**2 + z_live.imag**2>threshold**2`

while less nice looking is about 50% faster because it saves a square-root of all the elements.

To time it, I used

```
t1 = time()
image = julia_set(mapping=mapping,
                  min_coordinate=-1.5 - 1j,
                  max_coordinate=1.5 + 1j,
                  iterations_count = 255,
                  width=1920,
                  height=1080)
print(time() - t1)
```

Before: 3.16s
After 2.21s

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Did you measure the times for this specific line or for the full script? Because I don't see any performance gain when measuring times of running the `julia_set` function.

Comment: Timing info added, my guess is that you timed image showing or something.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't understand something, but 3.21s is more than 3.16s, and I don't see the 50% improvement.

Comment: yes, that's because I mistyped 2 as 3

Comment: Well, that's weird, I get 10% longer times with your suggestion. I guess I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: Are you running the revised code?

Comment: Yes, double-checked, it runs slower for me. With your setup the revised code as in the Gareth's answer takes around 5.7s for me, and with your suggestion it takes around 6.3s. Are you using the same `mapping` as in the question?

Comment: yes. What version of python are you using? Also what OS? I'm 3.7 on linux

Comment: Huh! So, now I tried it on my home laptop, and now I see the difference: 2.89s vs 2.06s. (Linux, Python 3.7.0, NumPy 1.16.3) It's weird to see that it's faster than PC in my office... I don't remember the versions there, will add it tomorrow.

Comment: My guess is you're office has a version of numpy where real and imag copy rather than alias. For this to be better, it needs to not allocate a ton of memory.

Comment: Better late than never. My office PC has the following setup: Windows 8.1, Python 3.7.3, NumPy 1.16.4

Comment: Consider me stumped then.